# Convert array of numbers to audio waveform in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, waveform, audio-player

I have an array of numbers like var amplitude=[4,2.5,3,2,1,-0.5,2]. I want to plot this data as waveform [image: like this]

and then play this waveform using a audio player

**PS:** It's difficult for me to understand... I want to convert this array to a musical waveform that plays in audio player. I am new to this so didn't knew where to start from

Answer (score -1):

I presume you have audio captures somewhere in text form of a generic systole and a generic diastole?  You just scale them both and insert them in sequence.  For example, if the generic systole consists of a set of values y1, y2, y3, y4 . . ., then scale these up by the indicated magnitude (4, 5, 2, -0.5).  Also scale up the generic diatole by the indicated magnitudes (2, 3, 1, 2). Note that, in the original set of numbers, every other figure is the strength of a systole, while every other OTHER number represents the strength of the corresponding diastole.  Just dump these values into a file sequentially.  I don't think you need any "x" or "time" axis: the audio file just requires a set of amplitudes, one after the other, to "play."